# Create equipment in Autocad Plant 3d

Tags: c#, 3d, autocad

I want to create equipment from predefined shape in autocad plant 3d.
I retrieve shape and related parameters from attached Code.

```
            using (EquipmentHelper eqHelper = new EquipmentHelper())
            {                    
                PromptEntityResult res = ed.GetEntity("\nSelect equipment entity: ");
                ObjectId eqId = res.ObjectId;;
                EquipmentType eq = eqHelper.RetrieveEquipmentFromInstance(eqId);
                foreach (CategoryInfo equipmentComponent in eq.Categories)
                {              
                    ed.WriteMessage("\n" + equipmentComponent.DisplayName);
                    foreach (ParameterInfo item in equipmentComponent.Parameters)
                    {
                        ed.WriteMessage("\n\t" + item.Name + ";" + item.Value);
                    }                        
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a Custom Python Script for this, check this tutorial: [Custom Python Scripts for AutoCAD Plant 3D – Part 1](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2015/06/custom-python-scripts-for-autocad-plant-3d-part-1.html) (and follow the subsequent parts)

Comment: Dear Augusto, Thank you for your answer, I want C# code for my question.

Comment: The catalogs are in Python only... You may create a solid and convert into a equipment, but it will not be parametric